# Error:=(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024809), None)

Tags: python, win32com

I am converting Excel to Pdf using win32com library:

```
import win32com.client

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
o.Visible = False
wb_path = r"G:\EXCEL_TO_PDF.xlsx"
wb = o.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
ws_index_list = [1] #say you want to print these sheets
path_to_pdf="G:\EXCEL_TO_PDF.pdf"
wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()
wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,path_to_pdf)
```

While running this code, I got an error:

```
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4df48d880fdb> in <module>
      7 path_to_pdf="C:\EXCEL_TO_PDF.pdf"
      8 wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()
----> 9 wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,path_to_pdf)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in ExportAsFixedFormat(self, Type, Filename, Quality, IncludeDocProperties, IgnorePrintAreas, From, To, OpenAfterPublish, FixedFormatExtClassPtr)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024809), None)
```

Comment: Isn't there someplace you can look up the meaning of the returned values: -2147352567 and -2147024809?

Comment: Why does the code say `wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,path_to_pdf)` but the traceback says `wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,"G:\EXCEL_TO_PDF.pdf")`?

Comment: error code 80020009 is "an exception occurred" and 80070057 is "wrong parameter".

Comment: Are you sure you have your drives right? The code says: Excel on G:\. Error says: PDF on G:\. Can you provide a [mre] so we can get the same error?

Comment: @mkrieger1- Please now check the error...Ive edited it....Help me in solving this issue!!

Comment: @ThomasWeller What is the drive right?? N How to give permission to the drive?? You can copy this code and run it on your editor...you'll get the same issue...Please help me!!! I'm stuck at this issue or you have any alternative way to convert excel to pdf using python  please let me know.
Thank You!!

Comment: Sorry, the code works on my machine.